# how to run multiple APIs through collection runner with data file in postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have 5 APIs in my collection. am able to run it through postman collection runner for all APIs at static data. But i want to use dynamic data for all APIs. for 1 API am able to run multiple iteration through json or csv. please let me knpw how we can use dynamic data for all APIs in the collection. 
for ex:

```
my collection name: Sample test
   API1 --- i/p: userid, token
   API2 --- i/p: mobile,username
   API3 --- i//p: username,collectioname,router
```

I have csv file for i/p data to run no.of iteration. so i want to know how i can tell API1 parameters and API2 parameters in csv file. how system will run as per the csv file data.
Thanks in advance

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might need to expand the information in this question, there is not a lot of context here. An example of what you have done and what you have tried so far will help people to understand the question.

Comment: @DannyDainton: I have added details to above question.